# Is there a term for when two methods of the same object are on the stack, with a method of a different object in between?

Tags: function, design-patterns, methods, stack

I'm working on a best practices guide, and there's a particular (anti)pattern I want to mention; unfortunately, I don't know the official name for it. Here's an example:

Suppose we have two objects, `master` and `slave`, whose basic interface looks like this:

```
class Master {
    Slave slave;

    public void startSlave() {
        slave.doWork();
    }

    public void onSlaveFinished() {
        slave.dispose();
    }
}

class Slave {
    Master master;

    public void doWork() {
        // ...do some work

        master.onSlaveFinished();

        // ...maybe do something here?
    }

    public void dispose() {
        // dispose of all resources held by this object
    }
}
```

In this arrangement, when `master.startSlave()` is called, the stack will end up looking like this:

```
slave.dispose()
master.onSlaveFinished()
slave.doWork()
master.startSlave()
```

The problem here is that when `slave.dispose()` finishes, `slave.doWork()` is still running, and it might try to do something with the resources that `slave` no longer holds.

So, my question would be, is there a name for when the stack ends up looking like this? Specifically, I mean that object A calls a method of object B, which ends up calling another method of object A, which can then leave object A in an inconsistent state.

I've tried googling a few terms I could think of ("stack overreach", "stack interleaving", "stack sandwich") but none of those seem to be recognized.

Comment: Your restriction to "which can then leave object A in an inconsistent state" implies you might be looking for something else. Would it change what you're trying to describe if the call that disposed 'slave' was to a different object?

Comment: @peteKirkham Fair question... I used disposing in the example because I think it clearly demonstrates the core issue, i.e. that the object's state changes while one of its methods is running. If I understand your suggestion correctly, you're picturing a stack like this: `[...] slave.doWork() -> master.onSlaveFinished() -> someOtherObject.dispose(slave)`. This does indeed cause the same issue. The reason I focused on calling one of `slave`'s methods is because it's usually the object's own instance methods that modify its state.

Comment: I don't know if there's a name for this problem, but note that things look bad even without `slave.dispose()`: `onSlaveFinished()` is effectively called mid-`startSlave()` which means `Master` class invariants _may_ be broken at this point.

Comment: @Abstraction That's entirely true. The point I'd eventually get to with this is that both `slave.doWork()` and `master.onSlaveFinished` should be called asynchronously (at least in JS that's how I'd approach it).